# How do I create a searchable help file?

Tags: search, help-files

I am writing a help file for a product and I need the help file to be searchable.

The help file can be HTML, PDF, DOC, etc., but I need a way to search, list and bring the user to the relevant page. I am going to be writing many tiny pages, snippets and variations of other snippets; Essentially just a lot of text to make the help file searchable and useful.

I haven't seen any help file that works well. As in: I can ask it a question and it will bring up relevant results.

What program/product can I use to make a searchable help file? The solution must work on Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). The excellent [Python help file](http://usoft-training-pydjango.googlecode.com/svn-history/r19/trunk/arun_sutha/python_docs/python261.chm) and [online documentation](http://docs.python.org/) is generated with Sphinx, and is very search-friendly.

You can also generate other formats including PDF, EPub and man.